# CSS: When to use max-height / max-width on images?

Tags: html, css

When does it make sense to use `max-height` or `max-width` on an image?

Does it help if I don't specify the actual dimensions of the image because I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense when you have images of unknown width (for example, user uploaded content) that you do not want to exceed a certain area.

If I remember correctly, the property is not supported by IE6. It is however by IE7: [Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width#)

Comment: Assuming the actual image dimensions are not specified, does the web browsers HTML render first allocate an image placeholder equal to the size of the max-height and max-width? If so, that would be great and then - once the browser knows the actual image dimensions - size appropriately

Comment: I don't know, but it would hardly make sense, would it? In most cases, the image will be smaller than the max- value, and all the placeholding was for naught.

Comment: On IE8 max-width don't work again (great!) It's also explained in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

it also a good practice to hold the size of an image list that contains landscape and portrait format